# Como enviar notificações (push) para um usuário específico (da aplicação) pelo Firebase?

Tags: android, ionic, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou desenvolvendo aplicações usando o framework Ionic. Uma das grandes dúvidas que tenho é como faço para trabalhar como notificações remotas (diferente das notificações locais, facilmente geradas pelo Ionic).

Utilizando o Firebase, consegui gerar notificações remotas para todos os dispositivos e para dispositivos específicos, utilizando o que eles chamam de "registration_id". No entanto, esse código representa um dispositivo, e não o usuário.

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma aplicação com dez usuários onde todos utilizam o mesmo dispositivo. A minha dúvida é a seguinte: **Como faço para enviar uma notificação específica para um (ou mais de um) desses usuários?**

Eu pensei inicialmente que este problema se resolveria com uma tabela relacional, onde seria possível relacionar o ID do usuário da aplicação com seu último *registered_id*, sendo necessário assim, atualizar esta tabela, se necessário, a cada login. No entanto, vejo que esta solução possui algumas falhas.

Answer (score 2):

Há duas formas de você fazer isso. A primeira é utilizando os [grupos do Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group?hl=pt-br). O grupo é o conjuto de dispositivos de um usuário. (eu ainda não utilizei esse recurso do Firebase, então não sei se é fácil a implementação)

A segunda forma é criando um tópico para o usuário (ex: `user-<ID>`) e genrenciar os dispositivos desse usuário, adicionando-os ao tópico, ou removendo.